# which one is preferable to store characters, vector<char> or string?

Tags: c++

I want to store  the characters  and  following operations are performed

1. Add the characters
2. find the characters
3. delete the characters

I think all these operations have O(n) complexity for both `vector<char>`and `string` , which one I should prefer and why?

Comment: If data is binary I would use `std::vector`, if string then `std::string`

Comment: If you are working with "strings" then use a `std::string`.  It was built for them.

Comment: See also the note in this section of the Core Guidelines: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#note-341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `std::string` if you are actually working with *strings*.
This makes more sense to me from a *semantic* perspective than using `std::vector<char>`...

Note also that `std::string` implements an efficient **SSO** (small string optimization), that avoids expensive heap allocations for small strings. This optimization is not available with `vector<char>`.

In addition, note that `std::string` supports also **embedded NULs** (so you can even store sequences of sub-strings efficiently in cache-friendly contiguous memory in a single `std::string` object, if that makes sense for your particular context).

Answer (score 2):

Did you considered better time complexity? If you will store "big" number of characters you don't want O(n) complexity, which is the case for both string and vector. Maybe you should use unordered_map then you will have all operations in O(1) time, just count the number of each character:

```
std::unordered_map<char, int> chars_map;
```